# Inconsistent behaviour in Dictionary/IDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Take the following piece of code

```
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>
        {
            ["A"] = 1,
            ["B"] = 2,
            ["C"] = 3,
        };

        var dictionaryx = (IDictionary)dictionary;

        var x = dictionaryx["X"]; // return null
        var y = dictionary["Y"];  // throws KeyNotFoundException
```

It is interesting to see the element access through the indexer leads to two different behaviours in `x` and `y`. 
As in general, interfaces should give access to the same internal implementation. but in this case, it is different.

what is the catch here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is implementing both the generic version of `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` and the non-generic version (just `IDictionary` that yields an `Object`).

Looking at the source, you can easily see that the [indexer of the generic version](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,179) explicitly throws when the key is not found:

```
public TValue this[TKey key]
{
    get
    {
        int i = FindEntry(key);
        if (i >= 0) return entries[i].value;
        ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException(); // <-- this line
        return default(TValue);
    }
}
```

But the [non-generic version](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,616) does not:

```
object IDictionary.this[object key]
{
    get
    {
        if (IsCompatibleKey(key))
        {
            int i = FindEntry((TKey)key);
            if (i >= 0)
                return entries[i].value;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then, unless you explicitly cast your `Dictionary` to the non-generic version, you're calling the indexer that throws when the key is not found.

**Update (as per your comment):**

Since `IDictionary` (the non-generic version) was introduced in .NET 1.0 (when there was no support for generics yet) the only type it consumed and returned is obviously `System.Object` (which can be tested for `null`).

Hence, it made sense not to throw when key is not found because one could simply do this:

```
dict["nonExistingKey"] != null
```

But, once the generic `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` was introduced, the `TValue` can also be set to a value type (like `int` or `DateTime`) and the above pattern would have to be adjusted to:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dict["nonExistingKey"] != 0;
dict["nonExistingKey"] != default(int);
```

Which is less fluent, less standard and more cumbersome to use.

From "design perspective", I presume they decided to preserve backward compatibility for `IDictionary` while proactively throwing for the generic version.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this second explicit implementation ( _which I didn't see in my first look through_ ). I was more after a justification for this behaviour from the design perspective than where the code is or who wrote it. but no one had responded for 'why' its there except 'what' is there. 
I'm accepting this answer as this one is the most relative answer anyway.

Comment: @Sency, I updated my answer with a possible explanation

Answer (score 2):

`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<K,V>` implements many interfaces.

It implements `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<K,V>`, which specifies that access to non-existing keys using the indexer property should throw.

It also implements `System.Collections.IDictionary`, which specifies that access to non-existing keys using the indexer property should return null.

The default indexer of the Dictionary class is the first one - from `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<K,V>`. When you cast to `IDictionary`, you say you want the second behaviour.

Also, note that `((IDictionary)dictionary)["key"]` returns an object, while `dictionary["key"]` returns an int.